# Flexible properties mechanism

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Let's say I have a class called `Expense`. I can add various types of car related expenses - tank expenses, repair expenses, tickets etc. Some properties of expense are the same for all types like cost, date etc., but there are some differences. For example: when I fuelled my car I want to save information like did I fully filled up my tank or not. However when I'm saving repair I want to save some other info.

The problem is - how to create some sort of flxible properties mechanism?

What I came up with is to have two tables: `expenses` and `expenses_properties`. In `expenses` table I could store all basic, common data and `expenses_properties` would have following structure:

```
| Id | PropertyName | PropertyValue | ExpenseId
|  1 | IsFull       | "true"        |     1
|  2 | Stuff        | "2016-10-02"  |     1
```

The problem is, for `PropertyValue` column I would have to use specific type, like `nvarchar` for example. In this case, I wouldn't be able to sort those values correctly (eg. by date)? Or maybe I would?

I think that there has to be a better way to do this using Entity Framework Code First approach.

Comment: If you know the official term for this, *Entity Attribute Value*, you can do some further research. I'm sure it will make you think twice.

Comment: @Gert, thank you very much! Research really did make me think twice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create your class/object model first (rather than the other way around, i.e., starting with the database):

```
public abstract class ExpenseBase 
{
    public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}

public class FuelExpense : ExpenseBase
{
    public  Boolean FilledUp { get; set; }
}

public class OtherExpense : ExpenseBase
{
    public string SomeOtherProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then choose an [inheritance mapping strategy](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx).  I usually go with "Table per Concrete class" (TPC) in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

If there are different types of expenses, then it actually makes sense to have different classes (i.e. different tables). You can have `Expenses` where you can store common data and then `TankExpense` where you store specific "properties" with a column `ExpenseId` with can be a foreign key of Expense table Ids. When you need to retrieve an instance of expense you'll just retrieve if using EF and all the related expenses will appear:

```
if (myExpense.TankExpense.Length > 0)
{
    var isFull = myExpense.TankExpense[0].Full;
}
```